# Занимаюсь парсингом сайта akakce.com не выдаёт html после нескольких запросов

Tags: python, requests, beautiful-soup

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import pandas as pd
import time

df = pd.read_excel("input.xlsx") 
links = df['ссылка на закуп'].tolist()
    links = ["https://www.akakce.com/toz-deterjan/en-ucuz-amway-premium-konsantre-toz-camasir-deterjani-sa8-3-kg-fiyati,118177990.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-maskesi/en-ucuz-keune-care-keratin-smooth-mask-500-ml-fiyati,1339744691.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-kremi/en-ucuz-kerastase-nutritive-nectar-thermique-iris-royal-150-ml-fon-oncesi-bakim-sutu-fiyati,392448922.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-homme-densifique-bain-densite-250-ml-yogunluk-kazandiran-fiyati,7752448.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-densifique-bain-densite-250-ml-yogunluk-kazandiran-fiyati,4037946.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-specifique-bain-prevention-250-ml-dokulme-onleyici-fiyati,4987915.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-bakim-yagi/en-ucuz-kerastase-elixir-l-huile-originale-100-ml-fiyati,1907370.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-genesis-homme-bain-force-quotidien-250-ml-fiyati,1873714967.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-genesis-bain-nutri-fortifiant-250-ml-dokulme-karsiti-guclendirici-fiyati,684956632.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-discipline-bain-fluidealiste-250-ml-sulfatsiz-duzlestirici-fiyati,38909909.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-spreyi/en-ucuz-kerastase-specifique-stimuliste-125-ml-dokulmeye-karsi-enerji-veren-fiyati,4037965.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-resistance-bain-force-architecte-250-ml-kuvvet-banyosu-fiyati,1907547.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-homme-densifique-bain-densite-1000-ml-yogunluk-kazandiran-fiyati,36143700.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-densifique-homme-30x6-ml-yogunlastirici-fiyati,91591357.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-resistance-bain-therapiste-250-ml-islem-gormus-saclar-fiyati,6460703.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-specifique-bain-divalent-250-ml-yagli-saclar-dengeleyici-fiyati,4888077.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-bakim-yagi/en-ucuz-kerastase-elixir-ultime-the-imperial-100-ml-boyali-saclar-bakim-yagi-fiyati,3834433.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-kremi/en-ucuz-kerastase-nutritive-creme-magistral-150-ml-durulanmayan-fiyati,15856134.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-nutritive-8h-magic-besleyici-gece-serumu-90-ml-fiyati,502705924.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-kremi/en-ucuz-kerastase-genesis-thermique-dokulme-karsiti-isidan-koruyucu-krem-150-ml-fiyati,697838268.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-bakim-yagi/en-ucuz-kerastase-chronologiste-huile-de-parfum-100-ml-sac-parfumu-fiyati,863644767.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-genesis-homme-sac-dokulmesine-karsi-guclendirici-serum-90ml-fiyati,1875030777.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-blond-absolu-cicaplasme-isiya-karsi-koruyucu-serum-150-ml-fiyati,451126563.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-specifique-bain-anti-pelliculaire-250-ml-yagli-kepekli-sac-fiyati,106950372.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-symbiose-bain-creme-anti-pelliculaire-nemlendirici-hucresel-250-ml-fiyati,328210419.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-maskesi/en-ucuz-kerastase-specifique-hydra-apaisant-200-ml-komple-yapilandirici-fiyati,74039952.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-densifique-jeunesse-100-ml-yogunlastirici-genclik-aktivatoru-fiyati,824329294.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-maskesi/en-ucuz-kerastase-resistance-therapiste-200-ml-islem-gormus-fiyati,6483208.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-curl-manifesto-bain-hydratation-douceur-250-ml-fiyati,1184867252.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-resistance-bain-extentioniste-250-ml-saglikli-uzayan-saclar-icin-guclendirici-fiyati,368451568.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-bain-riche-chroma-absolu-hasar-gormus-boyali-saclar-icin-250-ml-fiyati,1648769208.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-serumu/en-ucuz-kerastase-blond-absolu-huile-cicaextreme-100-ml-fiyati,1032676312.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-k-chronologiste-bain-revitalisant-250-ml-bas-derisi-canlandirici-fiyati,5758450.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sampuan/en-ucuz-kerastase-resistance-bain-volumifique-250-ml-hacim-veren-fiyati,5353562.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-maskesi/en-ucuz-kerastase-genesis-masque-reconstituant-200-ml-dokulme-karsiti-yogun-guclendirici-fiyati,805845743.html",
"https://www.akakce.com/sac-maskesi/en-ucuz-kerastase-nutritive-masquintense-riche-derin-besleme-saglayan-yogun-200-ml-fiyati,68005155.html"]
user = UserAgent()



def get_data(LINK):
    cookies = {
    '_gcl_au': '1.1.134425695.1692012992',
    'AAANSK': '645958220%7CD6DC',
    'ASPSESSIONIDCCBCSRDS': 'CCMJLDNACGJMLPAFCILGNCLN',
    '_gid': 'GA1.2.1307004319.1692012992',
    'cf_clearance': 'i14TuciAmrZufpX2pRq0C6McXQQBJYKRU.1hkMBGKlQ-1692017879-0-1-11454229.59ad1225.4b97a3c9-160.0.0',
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.554256315.1692012992',
    '_ga_SNSZLV7115': 'GS1.1.1692012991.1.1.1692022459.0.0.0',
}

    headers = {
    'authority': 'www.akakce.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7',
    'accept-language': 'ru-RU,ru;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7',
    'cache-control': 'max-age=0',
    # 'cookie': '_gcl_au=1.1.134425695.1692012992; AAANSK=645958220%7CD6DC; ASPSESSIONIDCCBCSRDS=CCMJLDNACGJMLPAFCILGNCLN; _gid=GA1.2.1307004319.1692012992; cf_clearance=i14TuciAmrZufpX2pRq0C6McXQQBJYKRU.1hkMBGKlQ-1692017879-0-1-11454229.59ad1225.4b97a3c9-160.0.0; _ga=GA1.1.554256315.1692012992; _ga_SNSZLV7115=GS1.1.1692012991.1.1.1692022459.0.0.0',
    'if-modified-since': 'Mon, 14 Aug 2023 14:03:02 GMT',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not.A/Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="114", "Opera GX";v="100"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/114.0.0.0 Safari/537.36 OPR/100.0.0.0',
    }

    response = requests.get(
    LINK,
    cookies=cookies,
    headers=headers,
    )

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    prices_no = soup.find_all(class_ = "pst_v8 noprice")

    delivery = soup.find(class_ = "pl_v8 pr_v8")
    
    soup = BeautifulSoup(delivery.__str__().replace('', ''), 'lxml')
    
    price_delivery = soup.find(class_ = "pt_v8")
    count = soup.find(class_ = "stock_v8")
    html_file = open("filename.html","w", encoding='utf-8')
    html_file.write(response.text)
    html_file.close()
    return {
        'prices_no': len(prices_no),
        'price_delivery': price_delivery,
        'count' : count,
    }

g = 1
for link in links:
    print(f'------------------{g}----------------')
    data = get_data(link)
    g+=1
    if data['prices_no'] >= 1:
        print("0")
    else:
        time.sleep(3)
        print(link)
        try:
            print(data['price_delivery'].text[1:-3])
        except:
                for i in range(100):
                    try:
                        data = get_data(link)
                        print(data['price_delivery'].text[1:-3])
                        break
                    except:
                        time.sleep(3)

                        print('no')
            
                
        try:
                print(data['count'].text.split(" ")[1])
        except:
                print('1')
```

помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Ищите обход cloudflare